# How to mock which is returning list of integers on some where condition?

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

I blocked in below step

```
var ids = _repository.GetIQueryable<Customers>().Where(lrt => lrt.IsActive == true &&
                       lrt.NextRoleId == defaultRoleSetting.RoleId &&
                       lrt.NextUserId == null).Select(x => x.MasterId).Distinct().Take(100).ToHashSet();
```

I tried this but I don't find the right Returns syntax

```
_mockRepository.Setup(s => s.GetIQueryable<Customers>()).Returns<List<int>>(ids =>
{
  return ????;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by below code my issue solved thanks every one.

```
var fakeCustomers = FakeCustomers();
_repository.Setup(s => s.GetIQueryable<Customers()).Returns(fakeCustomers.AsQueryable());
    
    private List<Customers> FakeCustomers()
            {
                string fakeData = @"[{
      'Id': '118',
      'CreatedBy':'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
      'SId':'4',
      'UserId':'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
      'NId':'7'
    }]";
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Customers>>(fakeData);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are creating a setup for `GetIQueryable<Customers>` you'd not return a list of integers, but instead an `IQueryable` of `Customers` objects that are filtered afterwards:

```
IQueryable<Customers> models = new Customers[]  {
    new Customers() { MasterId = 1, IsActive = true, NextRoleId = nextRoleId, ... }, 
    new Customers() { MasterId = 2, IsActive = false, NextRoleId = nextRoleId, ... }, 
    new Customers() { MasterId = 3, IsActive = true, NextRoleId = nextRoleId, ... }, 
  }).AsQueryable();

_mockRepository
    .Setup(s => s.GetIQueryable<Customers>())
    .Returns(models);
```

In this sample, you create an array of `Customers` objects and set the properties of the customers so that the filter afterwards works on the `IQueryable`. Which properties to set on the `Customers` objects depends on the classes and your test case.

Comment: Depending on how many times the `GetIQueryable<Customers>()` is called it might make sense to store the expected return value in a variable. With that the `Returns` will not recreate the same collection over and over again. BTW that `return` keyword is not needed.